# How to place a kinked arrow above a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

or optionally with a sharp kink:

[image]

Is that possible?

I stumbled across [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232887/how-to-place-arrows-horizontally-and-vertically-beside-matrix) and some answers where tikz was used but wasn't able to adjust it to my need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.se, please consider giving an MWE. This will help us a lot to answer your question accurately, also saves us time from going to our crystal balls `;-)`.

A starting point

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40535/matrix-with-arrows-and-labels
\begin{document}
\[
  X = \qquad \bordermatrix{~  &  ~ & ~ & ~ & ~
                        & ~  \cr
                    \tikzmark{varrowtop} ~ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\tikzmark{harrowright} \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr
                    \tikzmark{varrowbottom}~ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
                    }
\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[->] (varrowbottom) -- ([yshift=3ex]varrowtop)  -- ([yshift=3ex]harrowright)
            node[midway,above] {};
}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

**Smooth corners:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}
\begin{document}
\[
  X = \qquad \bordermatrix{~  &  ~ & ~ & ~ & ~
                        & ~  \cr
                    \tikzmark{varrowtop} ~ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\tikzmark{harrowright} \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr
                    ~ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr
                    \tikzmark{varrowbottom}~ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
                    }
\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[->, rounded corners] (varrowbottom) -- ([yshift=3ex]varrowtop)  -- ([yshift=3ex]harrowright)
            node[midway,above] {};
}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Nice, but notice that there is a `tikzmark` package (which has the advantage of working even if the marks are defined *after* their usage...)

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the remark. Till now, I did not knew its existence. I will take a note of it and go through it when I have some time. And, ensure it gets reflected in my future answers `:-)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrow by using the TikZ nodes created by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[X = 
\quad 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz [-> , rounded corners = 2mm ]
     \draw ([xshift=-2mm]last-|1) |- ([yshift=2mm]1-|last) ; 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]