# How to place arrows horizontally above/below a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows

I am trying to draw arrows next to a table like this:

[image: table]

I was able to draw vertical arrows using the technique [shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60626/227362):

```
$\left.
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline medium & high & high \\
    \hline low & medium & high \\
    \hline low & low & medium \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\right\uparrow
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Impact}$
```

[image: table latex]

However I have no idea how to draw the horizontal arrow on top of the table. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232903/227362) seems to use the same technique to draw horizontal arrows but I was unable to adapt it. It should also be possible to [use TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40539/227362) but I would like to keep it simple.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487732/134144 might also be useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do the answers to this question help you solve your problem? [Annotating a table with arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503855/138900)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked for this but I just stumbled on it.
Since you asked for a `tikz` solution, here's a simple one.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\spc{7pt} % Space between array and arrows, adjuts the arrows length automatically

\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-stealth,shorten >=\spc, shorten <=\spc}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[inner sep=\spc] (t)
        {
        \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{c|}}
        \hline medium & high & high \\
        \hline low & medium & high \\
        \hline low & low & medium \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        };
    
    \draw[myarrow] (t.north west) -- (t.north east) node[midway,above] {Likelihood};
    \draw[myarrow] (t.south east) -- (t.north east) node[midway,below,sloped] {Impact};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows around array]

Comment: This solution is clean and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just with `xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{array, rotating, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

$\xrightarrow[%
  \left.\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\sffamily}Sc|}}
    \hline medium & high & high \\
    \hline low & medium & high \\
    \hline low & low & medium \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \enspace \right\uparrow\hskip-1em\rlap{\hskip 1.25em\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\sffamily Impact}}]
{\textsf{\normalsize Likelihood}\bigstrut} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,first-row,last-col,cell-space-limits=6pt]
\Cdots[line-style={solid,->}]^{\text{Likelihood}} \\
medium & high & high 
& \Vdots[line-style={xshift=3mm,solid,<-}]^{\text{Impact}} \\
low & medium & high \\
low & low & medium \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]